# Set cookie for domain instead of subDomain using NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: cookies, node.js, express, session-cookies

I have been using expressjs and mongostore for session management. Following is the code to configure store in expressjs,

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: conf.secret,
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
        cookie: { path: '/' },
        store: new MongoStore(conf.db)
    }));
});
```

I had mentioned the cookie path in the above code. But it sets the cookie in sub.domain.com instead of .domain.com. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Remember that setting cookies to main domain name will cost you additional network traffic. See [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free) from Yahoo guys.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

configure it like this:

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    cookie: { domain:'.yourdomain.com'},
    store: new MongoStore(conf.sessiondb)
}));
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a cookie for more than one domain?
  ex : cookie: { domain:'.yourdomain1.com','yourdomain2.com},

Comment: I just tried `example.com` and it worked. Is there any difference in adding a `.` in there?

Answer (score 42):

Try to use the following link to configure.

```
res.cookie('name', 'tobi', { domain: '.example.com', path: '/admin', secure: true });
```

**Link :** http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: Why when I just add this part "domain: '.example.com', " cookie is not added and when I delete it, cookie is added?

Comment: I just tried `example.com` and it worked. Is there any difference in adding a `.` in there?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, it throws error.
Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    cookie: { domain:'.yourdomain.com'},
    store: new MongoStore(conf.sessiondb)
}));
```

I have a reference link, from where you can take help to set domain in cookie
https://flaviocopes.com/express-cookies/